# how to use getDerivedStateFromProps instead of componentWillReceiveProps in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, getderivedstatefromprops, componentwillreceiveprops

I like to update my code to use getDerivedStateFromProps instead of componentWillReceiveProps as the I am receiving deprecated error. The component is receiving a date prop and every time the date is changed in need to run the getList with the new date. To do this I am using the follow code below

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    const {date} = this.props;
    if (nextProps.date !== date) {
      console.log('prop changed to : ', nextProps.date);
      this.getList(nextProps.date);
    }
  }
```

I tried the following but it does not work

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    const {date} = this.props;
    if (props.date !== date) {
      console.log('prop changed to : ', props.date);
      this.getList(props.date);
    }
    return;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getDerivedStateFromProps` does not look like the right tool for what you are trying to do. Instead use `componentDidUpdate`:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  const { date } = this.props;
  if (prevProps.date !== date) {
    this.getList(date);
  }
}
```

It's pretty rare to use `getDerivedStateFromProps`. For more information on when to use `getDerivedStateFromProps` I recommend [this article](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html)